# Twilio not working with https

Tags: php, node.js, https, twilio

After surfing around all night I stil can't find any reference to my issue

I currently use the Twilio js client library to make calls to mobiles using a browser - the example used is called browser-phone - (js & php)

As seen here : https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/twilio-client-browser-soft-phone

The Twilio example was working perfectly until chrome 47 stopped the getusernedia() unless requesting from a https website

Accessing via Http version shows as

Show status: "ready to call"

As soon as the page is accessed via: https://

The status changes to "offline"

It looks like the site being accessed by https is unable to create a capability token or something

I'm sorry if this has been covered but if tried google all night and I can't seem to find issue - can anyone please help?

The voice url of the twiml app is also pointing to a https site

Any pointers will be appreciated

Note: site has just been migrated to https as I thought that twilio would just work once requesting from https - ssl is also enable on twilio account dashboard

Answer (score 1):

RESOLVED:
The Twilio status showed as "offline" as script source was not https and so untrusted in https environment